# Unit Test Failed : ModuleNotFound - Class inheritance from the other script in the same folder

Tags: inheritance, python-unittest, python-3.10, python-unittest.mock

Trying to write a unit test on a Class with a class inheritance from a Class in another script ( both in the same directory ).
Patch to `sys.module`,  verify it's in the sys.module but still getting ModuleNotFound error.

Wonder if I'm doing anything incorrectly. A second eye on this would be great. Thanks!

- Project structure

```
root
|-- src
   |-- steps
      |-- project
         |-- script1.py
         |-- script2.py
   |-- test
      |-- steps
         |-- project
            |-- test_script1.py
            |-- test_script2.py
```

- script1.py

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = None
```

- script2.py

```py
# Not using the full path. we're running this on AWS when uploading ( submit py ) to s3, both scripts exist in the same folder.

from script1 import A

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
     self.age = None
  def get_name(self):
     print(self.name)
```

- test_script2.py

```py
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from src.steps.project.script1 import A

class TestB(TestCase):
   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
        modules = {"script1.A": A()}
        cls.module_patcher = mock.patch.dict("sys.modules", modules)
        cls.module_patcher.start()
   def setUp(self):
       # ModuleNotFoundError : No module name 'script1'
       from src.steps.project.script2 import B
```

Tried the above patch to sys.modules
It is indeed patched to system modules when script2 is being imported.
Still giving the same error ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to add a path search in `sys.path` in the script `test_script2.py`. So the `test_file2.py` becomes:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/root')

# add here your code
```

In the file `script2.py` you have to correct the import instruction of the module `script1.py` with a relative path:

```
#from script1 import A  <--- this is your import

from .script1 import A  <--- this is the correct import
```

Comment: @Amy I have updated my answer with an other solution that can be useful for you. Please give me a feedback